# Cython: ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, numpy, cython, shapes

I'm trying to translate my function from Python to Cython to increase its speed significantly. If I call it, however, it throws this error. I will show you a reduced code with only the part that is problematic.

**compiling cython file**

```
%run -i setup.py build_ext --inplace   

Error compiling Cython file:

hh_vers02.pyx:51:25: Compile-time name 'Iext' not defined
hh_vers02.pyx:51:25: Error in compile-time expression: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

**Cython file (.pyx)**

```
import numpy as np

def hhModel(Iext):
    DEF numSamples = Iext.shape[0]        # needs to be constant, that's why i used DEF
    cdef float v[numSamples]

    return v
```

**create "Iext"**

```
# create stimulus vector
def create_stimulus_vector(nA, stimulus_length, zero_length, dt, plotflag):
    "create_stimulus_vector(2.5[nA], 1000[ms], 500[ms], 0.01[step/ms])"
    start           = int(zero_length*1/dt)                      #  5.000
    length          = int(stimulus_length*1/dt+2*start)          # 20.000
    stop            = length-start                               # 15.000  
    stimulus_vector = np.zeros(length)                           # array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])
    stimulus_vector[start:stop] = nA                             # array([ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.])
    if plotflag:
        plt.plot(np.linspace(0, length*dt/1000, length), stimulus_vector)
        plt.title("One Stimulus Vector")
        plt.ylabel("[nA]")
        plt.xlabel("[s]")
    return stimulus_vector

Iext = create_stimulus_vector(2.5, 1000, 500, 0.01, 1);
```

I tried million things primarily suggested [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html), including the following alternatives, which haven't changed the error though. Now I'm pretty desperate.

```
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

1) def hhModel(np.ndarray Iext):
2) def hhModel(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] Iext):
3) def hhModel(np.ndarray Iext):
       assert Iext.dtype == DTYPE
```

The error persists after restarting the kernel. I use Python 3.6.2 and IPython 6.1.0 in Jupyter Notebook (installed via Anaconda). I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: DEF is for compile-time constants. `Iext.shape[0]` is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Svenno, check the edit I made on your other post, it should fix it.